# Rails: I want to limit the selections available in form.html.erb based on logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selection, limiting

I need to reduce the selectable items to what is appropriate considering what was previously established.

Say I have [Class] **has_many** [Order] **has_many** [Family]
*(Remember old-school version of Kingdom Phylum Class Order Family Genus Species?)*

When the data-entry person has previously selected, say, the **four-legged mamals** [Class],

and the **Canids** [Order]  (I have no clue if this is at all right, but I hope you get the point),

They should **just** get Wolves, Foxes, and Dogs, etc. as their choices since they've narrowed it down that far.
I don't want to give the operator a list of [Families] like Cats or Crows or Crocodiles.

How do I go about that?

Comment: Checkout this [Dynamic Select Menus](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) railscast, I think it might be just what you need to help you accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you're trying to draw, say, the `Family` select box like this:

```
<%= collection_select :family_id, Family.all, :id, :name %>
```

But given that the user has already selected an order (let's assume you've instantiated that object as `@order`:

```
<%= collection_select :family_id, @order.families, :id, :name %>
```